# Get user input data from form in twig file with Symfony 4

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I'm trying to create a little search bar on my website with symfony 4. How do I get the the user input data from the form which can be used in the controller. The form looks like this :

```
 //.../navbar.html.twig

<form action="search" method="get" >
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be using a FormType and your form's method is 'GET':

First your need a name to your input. ex:

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
```

Then just pass the request service to your action in your controller and get the desired parameter.

```
public function yourAction(Request $request){
    $searchString = $request->get('search');
}
```

Edit: I strongly recommend using symfony's form component tho. Doc here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: using the link @Aurelien suggested is really good it will save you alot of time later on and will help you understand symfony much better.

Comment: SearchType Field. This renders an <input type="search" /> field, which is a text box with special functionality supported by some browsers. : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/search.html